# Activerecord return objects that match ALL attributes in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relational-division

Right now I have this query:

`@events = Event.joins(:packages).where("packages.kind IN (?)", packages).distinct`

And it returns objects that match just a single attribute in the `packages` array.

I would like ActiveRecord to only return objects that match *all* attributes in the given array. How would that be done with my query set up the way it is?

Comment: So say you have a packages array of `['crate', 'envelope']`. You want to return only events that have both a crate package and a envelope package? Not events that have just one and not the other?

Comment: That is correct. I've built out a checkbox system for my page and want to return all objects that match every checkbox that is checked.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like there must be a simpler way of doing this. But, in Postgres, try:

`Event.joins(:packages).having('array_agg(packages.type) @> array[?]', packages).group(:id)`

---

Comment: Postgres is not liking the `@>` operator. See: `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]
LINE 1: ...BY "events"."id" HAVING (array_agg(packages.kind) @> array['...`

Comment: That query is in Postgres 9.6.1; you might have a different version. Like I said, my gut tells me there's a much better way of doing this.

Comment: perhaps you can look at the answer down below and the problem I'm havin with it. I've linked to a gif of what is happening in with that solution down in the comments.

Comment: `packages.type` is, presumably, `varchar(n)` so the aggregate is `varchar(n)[]` but the array literal is `text[]`. You could throw a cast in to make `@>` happy: `array_agg(...)::text[] @> ...` or `... @> array[?]::varchar[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a query with multiple conditions

```
@events = Event.joins(:packages).distinct
packages.each do |package|
  @events = @events.where("packages.kind = ?", package)
end

@events
```

Comment: I see where you're getting at with that code but now it only returns objects if one attribute is selected. Even if Object one includes "attr1" and "attr2", it will fail to return anything if both "attr1" and "attr2" are selected. I can only select one attr at a time. This is a step backwards.

Comment: Ok, I've done some messing around with your code and I am getting closer to making it work. I had to rename the incoming query something different so there wouldn't be two `@events` for the controller to get confused with. But, there is a bit of a bug where depending on the order of what you click can return wrong items. The gif I will link will show the issue. http://imgur.com/YCxmrM2